# babel webpack import export keyword not working

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have created a simple HTML page with js now to add more functionality I have added webpack and install some node packages and run `npm start webpack` it starts fine and I can access localhost:8080 but it throws the error of import and export keyword.

#### package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "webpack": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot",
    "start": "http-server"
},

"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "jsxobj": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.12.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
```

#### webpack.config.js

```
var nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
module.exports = {
  entry: "./js/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  target: "node",
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".html", ".js", ".json", ".css", ".less"]
  }
};
```

#### js/index.js

```
import { fetchImage } from "../alphabet.js";

let i = 0;
const colorBox = {
    red: "#f00000",
    green: "#38c138",
    blue: "#0a6de8",
    orange: "#e69110",
    chocolate: "#1b1818",
    purple: "#632363",
    yellow: "#f1e904",
    bottle: "#102923",
    black: "#000000",
    white: "#d4d4d4"
};

const len = Object.keys(colorBox).length;

document.addEventListener(
    "keydown",
    e => {
        const key = e.key;
        i++;
        i = i % len == 0 ? 1 : i;
        let qs = document.querySelector(".alphabet");
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = Object.values(colorBox)[i];
        let str = key.toUpperCase();
        qs.innerHTML = str;
        fetchImage(key);
    },
    false
);
```

#### alphabet.html

```js
"use strict";

const fruits = {
  a: "apple",
  b: "banana",
  c: "coconut",
  e: "elephant",
  g: "grapes",
  l: "lemon",
  m: "mango",
  o: "orange",
  p: "pineapple",
  s: "strawberry",
  t: "tomato"
};

export const fetchImage = letter => {
  console.log("letter", letter);
  const myHeaders = new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
  });
  const myInit = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: myHeaders,
    mode: "same-origin"
  };

  const fruit = fruits[letter] || "tamarindo";
  console.log("fruit", fruit);

  const myRequest = new Request(`./fruits/${fruit}.png`, myInit);

  fetch(myRequest)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.blob();
    })
    .then(function(myBlob) {
      console.log("inside then");
      var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
      const img = new Image(200);
      img.src = objectURL;
      let element = document.getElementById("figure");
      while (element.firstChild) {
        element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
      }
      element.appendChild(img);
    });
};
```

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto/ repeat(2, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  color: white;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.alphabet {
  font-size: 25em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <section class="alphabet"></section>
    <figure id="figure"></figure>
  </div>
  <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

#### alphabet.js

#### .babelrc

```
{{
    "presets": ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
}
```

How make simple JS program to understand export and import keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `target: node` in webpack, which is not supposed to work on browser, especially with nodeExternals. Try to remove the following lines:

- `target: "node"`: is used when the script would be used by nodejs, just remove it and it will be set as `target: "browser"` by default.
- `externals: [nodeExternals()]` - it means do not bundle these packages into the resulting file, but in this case browser wouldn't be able to find them. Just remove this line.

---

#### update

Working [gist](https://gist.github.com/eldar-gamisoniya/d5df66a5da18b8c75364e4d91e109980)

The main changes:

- updated script in `index.html`
- `package.json`: for simplicity, removed unnecessary packages and update babel-related packages (in order to work with babel 7), and updated `webpack` script (see in the comments)
- `webpack.config.js`: removed `target: "node"` and all node-related stuff

Comment: I added the `externals` line on suggestion over some article as I need to use fs package of node in my javascript page. I mean  my requirement is to find out all file names from one directory and there is only one node inbuilt `readdir()` package in my knowledge.

Comment: according to the snippets you provided, you are using html page, which means you are running it in the browser. The only way browsers allow to read files is by providing them in `input` elements, you can't use `fs` package from there. There's [non-standard implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API), but it has very limited support and it's highly discouraged from using it.

Comment: your suggestion are good but still getting error of `unexpected token export`

Comment: @pro.mean you are also including the wrong file in html. `<script src="./js/index.js"></script>` - this is your original file, while should be webpack's output - `<script src="./build/bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: not working: it gives error: GET http://localhost:9000/build/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
22:47:23.891 localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:9000/build/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: it' actually not creating any bundle.js at all

Comment: @pro.mean i made in work in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/eldar-gamisoniya/d5df66a5da18b8c75364e4d91e109980).

Comment: "it' actually not creating any bundle.js at all." -
that's because you were using webpack-dev-server, which creates files in memory and serves them. Usually html is processed by [html-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/), but i haven't included it here for simplicity.